# C++ - Single Linked List - Ideas

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

I want to write a method to remove consecutive items with duplicate data values from a singly linked list. The method should return the number of items removed.  The method should clean up memory as required, and should assume that memory was allocated using new.

For example, passing in the list
->a->b->c->c->a->b->b->b->a->null
should result in
->a->b->c->a->b->a->null
and return 3

The list item definition and function declaration are given below

struct litem {
     char data;
     litem* next;
};

int remove_consecutive_duplicates( litem*& list );

```
I have a simple logic to check the next element recursively & removing the element if its duplicate. 
But, i would like to know how many efficient ways to do this ?  All ideas welcome from C++ gurus..
```

Comment: If it is homework you can tag it as so

Comment: You don't have to be a *C++ guru* to do your homework. And you don't have to do it *recursively* either ;)

Comment: What you need to realize is that if you have to iterate through ALL elements in a container, the most efficient method to do so will always be `O(n)`. You can definitely write recursive algorithms to solve in O(n) but you probably don't need to, at least in this case (also, it's very easy to screw recursive algorithms up efficiency-wise). A simple pass through the list will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::list`, and before pushing element on it you must check:

```
if ((*l.rbegin()) == next)
{
    return;
}

l.push_back(next);
```

Answer (score 1):

in meta language:

```
item = items.first
while (item != null) {
    while (item.next != null && item.value = item.next.value) {
        temp = item.next
        item.next = item.next.next
        temp.dispose
    }
    item = item.next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there's not a lot to optimize here. Returning the number of items used is just a case of incrementing a counter. Basically, if you find that litem->data == litem->next->data, then you need to do the removal like so:

```
litem* tmpItem = currentItem->next;
currentItem->next = tmpItem->next;
delete tmpItem;
```

Keep iterating until currentItem->next == NULL, to avoid referencing beyond the end of the list.